# Scrolling UITableView stops video playback

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I've a UIViewController divided into a UIImage view that streams a video updating image view frame by frame and a UITableView that loads tweets. But when I try to scroll the table view video stops playing. It's because both Image view and tableview have to update UI and that needs to be done in the main thread. Is there a workaround to achieve this without halting any process?[image: Screenshot of Storyboard]

Comment: I don't have a solution, but this happens because UIScrollView changes the current run loop to 'UITrackingRunLoopMode'. I you try to search something like that I'm pretty sure that you can find a solution

Answer (score 0):

UITableView reuses cells to save memory, once your cell is hidden that cell is reused for different content. This is done through the reusable cell id. 
You can try setting a different id for the video cell.